# Node serialport doesn't work after packaging by pkg

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing a node.js app that is communicating with a credit card reader via serial port.
I use 'Node serialport' and it works very well.

But after packaging by pkg, console shows the error messages like below and serialport doesn't work.

---

`(node:14044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\Debug\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\out\Debug\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\Debug\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\out\Release\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\Release\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\default\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\compiled\10.17.0\win32\x64\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\addon-build\release\install-root\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\addon-build\debug\install-root\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\addon-build\default\install-root\bindings.node
 → D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\lib\binding\node-v64-win32-x64\bindings.node
    at bindings (D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:126:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\snapshot\app_ver3.0.0\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\lib\win32.js:1:98)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1261:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:591:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1166:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
(node:14044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14044) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

---

Surely, there is no 'snapshot' directory in my D drive.
(I think it's a kind of default directory of Node serialport)

I have absoultely no idea.
Is there anyone who can solve this problem? : (

(Sorry for my bad english again)

Comment: You may want to read [this part](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg#:~:text=app.js%20a%20b-,Snapshot%20filesystem,-During%20packaging%20process) of README of pkg

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in one of my project. I think the problem is that pkg "don't know" yet how to handle .node file. So, during packaging, those files are left behind. I solved the issue by putting the @serialport folder (and its whole content) alongside the package file. Although it worked, I'm still curious on how to pack them together. I'm searching around and found your question.

I hope a better solution is coming..

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the error **"No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=node abi=108"**

The problem was solved placing the library in the package.json pkg configuration:

```
"pkg": {
    "scripts": [
      "dist/**/*.js"
    ],
    "assets": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "node_modules/@serialport/binding*/**/*"
    ],
    "outputPath": "build"
}
```